# Listview search does not refresh on backspace

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am setting the search filter like:

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                searchView.clearFocus();
            }
            else {
                CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Then:

```
Cur.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.getDirectoryList(constraint,stat);
            }
        });
```

in my DBAdapter:

```
public Cursor getDirectoryList(CharSequence constraint,String stat) {
        open(); 
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1);

        String asColumnsToReturn[] = { DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.id + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notificationfor + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.datetonotify + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.isextraordinary + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notificationdata + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.primaryid + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.type_notifications + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.radio_type_notfi + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.friend_name_not + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notif_image_Uri + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notifDob + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notificationdatefor };
        System.out.println(constraint);
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            String query;
            System.out.println("Executed"+stat);
            if(stat.equalsIgnoreCase("Off")){

                query ="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Notifications WHERE TypeNotification <> 'Event' AND RadioType <> '3'"+" AND DateToNotify < '"+getCurrentDatePlusOne().toString()+"'"+" UNION SELECT * FROM NotificationsCron WHERE TypeNotification <> 'Event' AND RadioType <> '3' ) T ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)";

            }else{

                query ="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Notifications WHERE DateToNotify < '"+getCurrentDatePlusOne().toString()+"' UNION SELECT * FROM NotificationsCron) T ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)";

            }

            return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);


        } else {
            String value = "%" + constraint.toString() + "%";
        //  if(stat.equalsIgnoreCase("Off")){
        //      return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE1,asColumnsToReturn,"(NotificationDateFor like ? OR FriendsName like ?)" +" AND TypeNotification <> 'Event' AND RadioType <> '3' ORDER BY DateToNotify ASC",new String[] { value, value}, null,null, null);

        //  }else{
                return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE1,asColumnsToReturn,"(NotificationDateFor like ? OR FriendsName like ?)" +" ORDER BY DateToNotify ASC",new String[] { value, value}, null,null, null);
        //  }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, but when I use backspace the list does not restore to the original cursor. If I type Jim, it displays all the people with name Jim but when I use a backspace the filter gets stuck at names starting with J. WHat do I miss here?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

Comment: I think there is something else what is missing here, I am providing the new cursor based on the constriants. It should and must update without using notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: I resolved the same issue with creating two different ArrayLists, one is temp and other is main, and copying and clearing values and retrieving final list from them